# What is the site youranswers.info and why does it have copies of questions and answers on stackoverflow/superuser etc?

Tags: discussion, licensing, scraping

I noticed that the site http://youranswers.info had copies of questions, answers and comments of stackoverflow and superuser questions (it might probably have questions on other stackexchange sites as well)

For example this question on super user:

https://superuser.com/questions/784578

Is available here on youranswers.info:

http://youranswers.info/question/view/en/YUhSMGNEb3ZMM04xY0dWeWRYTmxjaTVqYjIwdmNYVmxjM1JwYjI1ekx6YzRORFUzT0M5bWFXNWtMV3RsZVMxdlppMXBibk4wWVd4c1pXUXRZVzVrTFdGamRHbDJZWFJsWkMxcGJuTjBZVzVqWlMxaFpHOWlaUzFoWTNKdlltRjBMWEJ5YjJabGMzTnBiMjVoYkMxM2FYUm9iM1Yw

Is this site a part of stackexachange? If not, it would appear that this site might use some kind of scraping mechanism to get the info. If so, is that allowed?